# SQL Server - subquery with xmlnamespaces and cross apply

Tags: sql-server, xml-namespaces, cross-apply

I want to use the results from the following to join to other tables:

```
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model' as ns1)
 select id,
        isnull(null, cast(substring(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 24, len(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))) as integer)) loc_id
   from MyOldXMLTable mo
   cross apply mo.x.nodes('/ns1:Entities/ns1:Entity/ns1:Attribute') as p(col)
where p.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'foundTheRightOne'
  and mo.id < 10
```

Results are:

```
+----+--------+
| id | loc_id |
+----+--------+
|  3 |     47 |
|  4 |     47 |
|  5 |     47 |
|  6 |     47 |
|  7 |     47 |
|  8 |     47 |
|  9 |     47 |
+----+--------+
```

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
select * from (
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model' as ns1)
 select id,
        isnull(null, cast(substring(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 24, len(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))) as integer)) loc_id
   from MyOldXMLTable mo
   cross apply mo.x.nodes('/ns1:Entities/ns1:Entity/ns1:Attribute') as p(col)
where p.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'foundTheRightOne'
  and mo.id < 10 ) as aa
```

... and then join it, but nope.  I keep getting syntax errors because of the ;WITH and the cross apply.  Anyone know how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITH XMLNAMESPACES applies to the whole query (it is very convenient, declare the namespace(s) once and use them anywhere in the query).
You could also use xquery/inline namespace declarations which they tend to get too verbose.

```
create table #myoldxmltable
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    x xml
);

insert into #myoldxmltable(x)
values(N'<ns1:Entities xmlns:ns1="http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model">  
  <ns1:Entity>
      <ns1:Attribute name="foundTheRightOne">
        <ns1:Entity href="http://test123.com/abc/1234567" />
      </ns1:Attribute>
  </ns1:Entity>
  </ns1:Entities>
');

--simple derived/as
with xmlnamespaces ('http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model' as ns1)
select *
from 
(
 select id,
        isnull(null, cast(substring(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 24, len(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))) as integer)) loc_id
   from #myoldxmltable mo
   cross apply mo.x.nodes('/ns1:Entities/ns1:Entity/ns1:Attribute') as p(col)
where p.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'foundTheRightOne'
  and mo.id < 10
) as aa;


--join with another table
with xmlnamespaces ('http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model' as ns1)
select *
from 
(
 select id,
        isnull(null, cast(substring(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 24, len(p.col.value('(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))) as integer)) loc_id
   from #myoldxmltable mo
   cross apply mo.x.nodes('/ns1:Entities/ns1:Entity/ns1:Attribute') as p(col)
where p.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'foundTheRightOne'
  and mo.id < 10
) as aa
join sys.columns as o on aa.id = o.column_id and o.object_id = 3; --sql2019 , abysmal execution !!??!!


--a different flavor, xquery namespace declaration (way too verbose)
--compare this with the query using xmlnamespaces
select *
from 
(
 select id,
        isnull(null, cast(substring(p.col.value('declare namespace ns1="http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model";(./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 24, len(p.col.value('declare namespace ns1="http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model"; (./ns1:Entity/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))) as integer)) loc_id
   from #myoldxmltable mo
   cross apply mo.x.nodes('
   declare namespace ns1="http://thatonecompany.com/rest/model";  
   /ns1:Entities/ns1:Entity/ns1:Attribute') as p(col)
where p.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'foundTheRightOne'--no need for ns1 declaration, path just references an attribute, no ns1
  and mo.id < 10
) as aa;


drop table #myoldxmltable;
```